# Why isn't there a 'price attribute for the 'product'?'

Tags: schema.org

http://schema.org/Product

Clearly, each product should have an associated price attribute, but there isn't in the 'product' schema. There is a http://schema.org/price.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

A Product does not have a price by itself, since a product itself does not have an intrinsic price. Instead, a Product can be [**Offer**](https://schema.org/Offer)ed at a price, in which case a [price](https://schema.org/price) (and other price-related properties e.g. [priceSpecification](https://schema.org/priceSpecification)) is attached to the Offer and not the Product.